# Error bcrypt, hash al cambiar contraseña

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy trabajando en el backend de un proyecto dentro del bootcamp que estoy haciendo y estoy teniendo problemas con el hash de una contraseña.
Este es mi codigo del cambio de contraseña

```
 updateUser: async (req, res) => {
        try {

            const {
                password
            } = req.body
            const user = await Users.findById(req.user.id)

            const samePassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

            if (samePassword) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Introduce una contraseña nueva, por favor, es la misma que anteriormente!"
                })
            }

            if (!password)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Introduce una contraseña, por favor"
                })

            if (password.length < 6)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "La contraseña debe tener minimo 6 caracteres!"
                })

            user.password = password
            
            await user.save()
            res.json({
                message: "Contraseña actualizada correctamente!"
            })

        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }
    },
```

y este es donde hago el hash de la contraseña :

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next){
    
    if(!this.isNew || !this.isModified('password')){
        return next();
    }

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>{
        if (err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err,hash) =>{
            if (err) return next(err);
            this.password = hash;

            next();
        })
    })
})
```

El problema es que me cambia la contraseña y ya no me hace el hash a la nueva contraseña y no veo el fallo.
He hecho console.log despues de     `if(!this.isNew || !this.isModified('password')){ return next(); }` y se vé que ahi ya no me funciona.

Alguna idea ?  Gracias de antemano

Comment: mira lo que te devuelve `this.isModified('password')`

Comment: El tema sería que está haciendo `.isNew ` y `.isModified`, estos dos métodos comparan un password viejo y uno nuevo. El nuevo lo pones con `user.password = password` y el viejo como lo obtiene?

Comment: Te refieres a esto :  ```  const newUser = new Users({
                name,
                email,
                password
            })

            // Save mongodb
            await newUser.save()

            const accesstoken = createAccessToken({
                id: newUser._id
            })

            res.json({
                accesstoken
            })
``` ?  Entonces como tendría que hacerlo ? Muchas gracias

Comment: LA contraseña me la modifica en la BBDD, pero sin el hash, sino directamente lo que yo pongo, por lo tanto no me la puede comparar con el hash. Como tendria que hacerlo ? Gracias anticipadamente

Comment: PROBLEMA RESUELTO :) . He vuelto a encriptar la contraseña antes de guardar el cambio y parece que funciona perfectamente :)  ` const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
            await user.save()`  , por si a alguien mas le pasa esto